# How to add text alongside an image in a container widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I’m trying to make a container which contains both an image and text. The problem I need help with is that I cannot add text alongside a picture. To be clear, I want the text and image to be inside the same container. I have been able to use a text widget if I place it outside of the container widget, but the result is text outside of my container, which is not what I want.

[This is what I have currently. This is the design I want, but I want to be able to put text along the right side of the picture; on the gray, empty part of the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZZoV.jpg).

Here is the code I currently have for my container:

```
body: ListView(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 500,
      color: Colors.white24,
      height: 125,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 265.0),
        child: Image.asset('images/HPerm.png'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I have tried everything that I could possibly think of. I have tried making a different container with different children, I’ve tried wrapping the current container that I have with other widgets, I have tried making functions and calling them inside the container, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the sample code...

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 500,
                  color: Colors.white24,
                  height: 125,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Image.asset('images/HPerm.png'),
                        const Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                          child: Text("Sample Text"),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, in Row widget...

Comment: Thank you! I changed the MainAxisAlignment to SpaceBetween, as that put my image back on the side. But thanks again!

Comment: Just saw your comment above. MainAxisAlignment.start works as well. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Probably You're new in Flutter. Don't give up. Try, try, try. Fake it until you make it.